# NextJS/Strapi Dynamic Routing with bad slug returns empty data instead of 404

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, strapi, swr

I am setting up dynamic routing in Next.JS 13 (using the App Router approach) and am using Strapi v4 for the CMS.

I am successfully grabbing data for my content type `work` by filtering the api request by a field in my Strapi content type called `slug`. The problem I am having is that when I go to a URL that does not have a corresponding `slug` in my `work` content type, say: `localhost:3000/works/asdf`, the page loads and just returns an empty data array instead of a 404 page, which is what I'd like it to do.

The folder structure is:

```
app/
  ├── works/
  │   ├── page.js
  │   └── [slug]/
  │       └── page.js
```

Here is what is returned from a call on my content type `work`:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "title": "Test Work Item",
                "description": "Test work description",
                "createdAt": "2023-08-07T21:11:53.187Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-07T21:12:45.925Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-08-07T21:11:54.526Z",
                "slug": "test-work-item",
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant Next.JS code

```js
'use client'
import useSWR from 'swr';
import axios from 'axios';

const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);

export default function SingleWork({ params }) {
    const { slug } = params;
    const { data, error } = useSWR(
        `http://localhost:1337/api/works?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}&populate=*`,
        fetcher
    );

    if (error) return <div>Error loading data...</div>;
    if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
        <div>My Post: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is where I've landed. This works, though this technically is still not a "real" 404 error, as a query without a corresponding slug still returns a 200. I think I need to rewrite the strapi controller to look for the slug instead of the id. If anyone knows of a better approach I'd appreciate that.

**EDIT:** I have rewritten the Strapi controller to look for the slug instead of the id, and now when I query in Postman, only actual slugs return 200, everything else returns a 404, but on my NextJS front end, all slugs still resolve.

**Front-end**

```js
'use client'
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data.data);

export default function SingleWork({ params }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { slug } = params;
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
        `http://localhost:1337/api/works?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}&populate=*`,
        fetcher
    );

    if (error) {
        return (
            <div>failed to load</div>
        )
    }
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )
    };

    if (!data[0]) {
        router.push("/404")
    } else return (
        <div>My Post: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    )
}
```

**Back-end**

```js
module.exports = createCoreController('api::work.work', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async findOne(ctx) {
        const { id } = ctx.params;

        const entity = await strapi.db.query('api::work.work').findOne({
            where: { slug: id },
            populate: true
        })

        const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);
        return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
    }
}));
```